# Windows 10 hostfile url to IP address of machine

Tags: windows, dhcp, localhost, hosts-file

Is it possible to use a fixed url to redirect to the IP of my own PC? I use DHCP and I have no problem with it but would like to use an url i.e. "server.local" to reach a web server deployed on the PC without always mixing up IP addresses?

Does the host file have options like this?

Comment: You can use `localhost`

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense!

Comment: You can also use `http://172.0.0.1` or `http://yourpcname`

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10, your hosts’ file is located at: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. You will need to edit the file with administrative privileges.

Click the Windows button and type Notepad in the search bar.
Right click on Notepad and then Run as Administrator.
You’ll be asked, “Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?”.
Choose Yes.
In Notepad, choose File then Open
Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts or click the address bar at the top and paste in the path and choose Enter.  If you don’t readily see the host file in the /etc directory then select All files from the File name: drop-down list, then click on the hosts file.
Add the appropriate IP and hostname at the end of your hosts’ file, select save and close the file.
Finally, you will want to flush your DNS cache for your computer to recognize changes to the file. Click the Windows button and search command prompt.
Right-click on Notepad and then Run as Administrator.
You’ll be asked, “Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?”.
Choose Yes.
Type the following command in the terminal and press Enter
ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: I see a perfectly good explaination (although an enter or two would have been helpful for readability), but I miss a simple "Yes, you can do it as follows" line at the top. Also, given that you can read what OP wants, you could add it into the answer as example: namely `server.local         172.0.0.1`